# How do you connect a hitachi CP-X400 projector to a Macbook

Tags: macbook

I need help with connect a macbook to the hitachi cp-x400 projector. there are only a few ports on the macbook; 2 usb, one firewire/printer type usb (not sure if it is firewire or what it is exactly, but it definitely is the printer sized usb), ethernet, and thats about it. Please help. PC usually work when i plug it in. I have it a regular usb plugged into the macbook connecting to the printer type usb port on the projector and its not working.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's not firewire\usb, it mini displayport (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort), so you should find wire with such connector on one side & vga\composite on other - (for projector connection)

Answer (score 0):

Yep that was exactly it. New Macs use mini displayports. after spending an hour and a half online trying to figure this fact out, and 2 hours going store to store before that asking if they have mac cable or accessories no one could tell me this simple fact. then another 2 hours driving around to go to Best Buy because they're the only place that has this besides Apple. $24.99 at best buy, although there was one for $29.99. I got the mini displayport to VGA, where the mini displayport to the DVI was only $19.99. If i got the mini displayport to VGA at apple it wouldve been $29.00... This is why i hate macs, they claim to make everything easier, but it just a hassle when you live in a PC world and Steve Jobs makes new cords or connector every 2 years so he can make on obsolete and sell new crap to a bunch of naive consumers, just so he knows mac people will have to by the crap he is selling if they still want to use their computers.

Comment: Actually now you just have ONE port that allows you to connect to VGA, DVI, HDMI or DisplayPort devices. That meany you can use Beamers (that usually have a VGA port), Displays (there are still a few using VGA, most use DVI and then again a few HDMI) or TV sets (mostly HDMI). In addition to that you are able to use the quite modern (but widely unkown/unused) DisplayPort which can be used to control quite big displays (4096x2560).